# Cannot run logstsh on windows

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat

I am trying to get the logs from logstash and send it to elasticsearch for visualising the logs using kibana but I am getting an error while running this code from logstash\bin directory 
`logstash -f logstashpipline.conf` 
The error says
 `Error: Could not find or load main class MyPC\Desktop\logstash\logstash-core\lib\jars\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar;`

```
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

This is my code:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "C:\xampp\apache\logs\access.log"
    type => "apache_access"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
  file {
    path => "C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log"
    type => "apache_error"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

output {
 elasticsearch {
   hosts => "localhost:9200"

   index => "apache_logs"
   document_type => "system_logs"
 }
 stdout {  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

this is the problem of 6.4.1 version of logstash.bat: redundant quotes are applied for %CLASSPATH%
So, you can fix it manually by editing logstash.bat file. Find and replace this line

```
%JAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% -cp "%CLASSPATH%" org.logstash.Logstash %*
```

with that one

```
%JAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% -cp %CLASSPATH% org.logstash.Logstash %*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to solved your problem as I had also the same problem and solved it.

If you are using windows, try to remove the space from path, move logstash to folder C:

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
logstash.bat -f logstashpipline.conf
```

Instead of:

```
logstash -f logstashpipline.conf
```